# SAML SSO work on Refresh of Browser for SFDC Community instance

Tags: saml-2.0

We have internal and community instance (website) SAML Enabled, and internal website work fine, where as community website required refresh or entering again website address in the same browser instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: there is not code written for this, its just SAML configuration for multisites. of which 1 site is working fine but the other one work only after refreshing the browser

Comment: 1. Navigate to this URL https://csuat.force.com/CustomersPartners/ 
2. You will be logged in and directed to  https://csuat.cs43.my.salesforce.com/CustomersPartners/  which has wrong domain.
3. Again navigate to this URL (when i again enter this URL in same borwser) https://csuat.force.com/CustomersPartners/  same window
4. You will be directed correctly

Answer (score 0):

this issue is fixed now, i have to use HTTP-Redirect instead HTTP-Post for multisite functioning in this use case.